# Is jQuery Mobile a lightweight version of original jQuery or jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mobile-website, jquery-mobile

Is **jQuery Mobile** a lightweight version of original jQuery or jQuery UI?

Is it a mobile version of jQuery? Whatever we can do with jQuery all possible with **jQuery mobile**?

Will all jQuery selectors work with **jQuery mobile**?

And if I want to use according like this http://www.mix26.com/demo/accordion/index.htm on latest mobiles. Is it possible to make same effect with "**jQuery Mobile**" library? or I will have to use desktop version of jQuery?

On mobile web development, When we should use jQuery and when **jQuery Mobile**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: jQuery Mobile is a new framework and **it's not** in any way a version/remake of jQuery nor jQuery UI. **It requires jQuery** as a base.

It also is not similiar to jQuery UI.

jQuery Mobile is supposed to be used to [progressively enhance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) applications so that they work on most platforms and look as good as possible. Most of jQuery Mobile magic is done with HTML5 `data-*` markup and a whole application can be done with `zero` lines of javascript.

For mobile browsers that fully support javascript more advanced functions can be used and jQuery Mobile provides some useful stuff for mobile development, such as `tap` or `swipe` events.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, a lightweight version of jQuery is [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/), which is pretty much jQuery without a bunch of extra code for compatibility with browsers that don't play nice.  I think it is what the OP thought jQuery mobile is.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like jQuery mobile is another version of original jQuery while jQuery UI will be also made available for mobiles, at least some controls.

I have found this post online which describes it:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/08/jquery-mobile.html

so for what I understand, jQuery mobile is a lightweight version of jQuery.

Comment: downvoters please add a comment if unhappy with my answer so that I do understand what I said wrong, if any! :)

Comment: This answer is being downvoted because the information provided is wrong. jQuery Mobile is not a lightweight version of jQuery. It is a framework that can be used to build the front-end of a mobile web application. It contains a set of form widgets (checkbox, radio buttons, select, etc) specifically designed to look/function well on mobile devices. It is _dependent on_ jQuery.